# Issue with disable-output-escaping on macOS and PHP 7.1

Tags: php, xml, apache, xslt

I have weird issue; I installed Apache 2.4 with PHP 7.1.8. But when trying to compile a HTML site using XML and XSL it keeps ignoring the "disable-output-escaping=yes" option.

Anyone has an idea what can cause it?

Here is my PHP code:

```
                $doc = $processor->transformToDoc( $this->_xml );
                $doc->formatOutput = true;
                return $this->cleanOut( $doc->saveXML() );
```

Regards,
Radek

PS: It works on many other servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of things can cause this. The most likely are:

(a) Your XSLT processor might not support disable-output-escaping (it's an optional and deprecated feature)

(b) You might be sending the XSLT output to a destination other than a serializer (for example, to a DOM tree)

Really, you shouldn't be using disable-output-escaping. 90% of the time it's only used by people who really haven't mastered the right way to do things in XSLT.

**LATER**

As is clear from the latest update your post, you are using transformToDoc, which writes the XSLT result tree to a DOM; you are then serializing the DOM using doc->formatOutput which uses the DOM serializer rather than the XSLT serializer; this has no knowledge of the disable output escaping attributes in the XSLT.

(The documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtodoc.php has a user-contributed comment pointing out that it's usually better to use transformToXML because that way, the XSLT processor gets to control the output format.)

I don't know anything much about the native PHP XSLT processor but the same problem occurs with other language environments.

Incidentally, you might like to know that XSLT 3.0 is now available for the PHP environment via the Saxon/C product (see www.saxonica.com). One of the reasons people resort to `disable-output-escaping` in XSLT 1.0 is because XSLT 1.0 doesn't provide easy ways to do grouping. This is fixed in later XSLT versions but unfortunately the PHP XSLTProcessor was never updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe my skills aren't that good but I have no idea how to open and close a div container in a loop depending on setting and current counter. Yet the issue is that it is a bit popular software and I can't change it like that. 
I am updating the original post with my code.

Comment: Yes, the 90% who misuse d-o-e have a mindset of "opening and closing containers" rather than building nodes in a result tree. It took me a few months to get past that stage myself, I remember it well.